# Network bandwidth & traffic monitoring

Tags: linux, firewall, hotspot, network-traffic

I have the following situation:

- Small network with about 30 PCs with wireless cards.
- A regular Asus wireless access-point which is connected to the server.
- Server is a normal x86 PC with Ubuntu Linux. Server connects to Internet by ADSL.

I want to monitor the traffic (visited sites & URLs) and bandwidth (total size of download data per weak) of all users, not limiting the quota or traffic shaping or QoS. Just monitoring, even not real-time.

I did a little research and I saw some firewalls, such as Untangle, ... or things like OpenWRT.

How would I go about monitoring the traffic in this situation?

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted.

Comment: This question calls for monitoring of traffic, not just bandwidth usage as in the duplicate link.